# How a request is handled when it is made from a servlet to the other server

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet created and hosted on TOMCAT server.
I know that every time a request is made, a thread handles the request and gets it processed by the servlet instance.
The request will have a calling user agent details, and thats how it will know where to send the response back.

Lets say that the servlet needs to make a call to another server for some information

So here is what's I am thinking

More browser(s) are making a request calls to the first server at the same time.
The servlet on the first server will have to make a request to the second server for information for each of the incoming requests from the browsers.

How does the servlet on the first server distinguish the responses it receives from the second server, as each response will be associated with a request made by the browser.

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

> The request will have a calling user agent details, and thats how it will know where to send the response back.

User agent details are not the means through which the server sends back the response. Once the browser fires a request to server (to tomcat server port), a TCP/IP socket is created between browser m/c and the server machine. And since tomcat is listening on that port OS, the tomcat spawns a thread to read the request and send back the response via HttpServletResponse.getWriter() object.

The same logic applies when a servlet running one tomcat server, say Tomcat1, connects to another tomcat, say Tomcat2, on a different machine.

> How does the servlet on the first server distinguish the responses it receives from the second server, as each response will be associated with a request made by the browser.

You might be using some http library, plain HttpURLConnection etc on Tomcat1 to send request to Tomcat2 that allows you to read the response. And once you read the response on Tomcat1, you could send back the response to browser via HttpServletResponse.getWriter() object on Tomcat1 server.

Comment: That puts some light to my understanding. But as there is only one servlet instance, how does the response from tomcat2 is wired to response of tomcat1. Doesn’t it overlap between the responses. I’m not able to understand the wiring up

Comment: Servlet instance wii be only one. But each request has its own socket and a thread. You can try a small example and that would really clear lot many things.